# This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-layout

I am getting the following error.

```
This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures-, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
Take a look at the docs for migrating an app: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
The plugin `audio_session` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command.
```

The app is already using Android embedding and I am using the Flutter 2.23 version. I checked this also. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

I am also not using the `audio_session` plugin and do not have any clue, which library is using it. Anybody can help?

Comment: whats the error you are getting after appying the changes from that upgrade guide link?

Comment: @srv_sud, I resolved this error. The error was in "AndroidManifest.xml" file in application tag.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this error by changing "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" to "${applicationName}" in application tag.

Previous configuration:

```
<application
  android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
  >
  <!-- code omitted -->
</application>
```

New configuration:

```
<application
  android:name="${applicationName}"
  >
  <!-- code omitted -->
</application>
```